# Pandas - Compute a value for each row, using information from previous rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a Pandas dataframe, df, which looks like this (with other columns):

| timestamp | player | event | location_x | location_y | location_z | dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001000 | Bob | 'PlayerMoveEvent' | 10 | 10 | 10 | ? |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001600 | Alice | 'PlayerJoinEvent' | NaN | NaN | NaN | ? |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001600 | Alice | 'PlayerMoveEvent' | 20 | 20 | 20 | ? |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001670 | Bob | 'PlayerMoveEvent' | 11 | 10 | 10 | ? |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001740 | Eve | 'PlayerMoveEvent' | 5 | 15 | 9 | ? |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001670 | Eve | 'PlayerQuitEvent' | NaN | NaN | NaN | ? |
| 2021-07-14 22:54:28.001820 | Alice | 'PlayerMoveEvent' | 18 | 20 | 19 | ? |

Every time a player moves, an event is triggered and their position is logged.

Now I want to figure out the distance √((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2) between two given players, in this case Alice and Bob, and add it to the end of the dataframe as a new column.

For a row with another player, or a non-'PlayerMoveEvent', it would just repeat the same value from the previous row, because it'd be using the older locations (I tried doing this by storing the locations as separate lists, shown below).

```
def player_distance(df, player_0, player_1):
    player_0_location = [None, None, None]
    player_1_location = [None, None, None]
```

I've tried many things (before I was using .apply with a lambda function "dist"), but now I'm trying to do it all in one function. I know that iterrows() isn't doing what I think it does below, because none of the below worked as an IF statement, even if they worked when tested manually outside of the function:

`if((df.loc[i]['player'][0]) == player_0) & (df.loc[i]['event'][0]) == 'PlayerMoveEvent')):`

`if((df.loc[i]['player'].item()) == player_0) & (df.loc[i]['event'].item()) == 'PlayerMoveEvent')):`

both of these neither work when type-casted to string

`if((df.loc[i]['player'].item() == player_0) & (df.loc[i]['event'].item() == 'PlayerMoveEvent')):`

`if((j['player'] == player_0) and (j['event'] == 'PlayerMoveEvent')):`

`if((j['player'].eq(player_0)) & (j['event'].eq('PlayerMoveEvent'))):`

```
def player_distance(df, player_0, player_1):
    player_0_location = [None, None, None]
    player_1_location = [None, None, None]
    for i, j in df.iterrows():
        # PROBLEM LINE
        if((df.loc[i]['player'][0]) == player_0) & (df.loc[i]['event'][0]) == 'PlayerMoveEvent')):
        # this line always gives a "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." error
            player_0_location[0] = df.loc[i, 'location_x'].values[0]
            player_0_location[1] = df.loc[i, 'location_y'].values[0]
            player_0_location[2] = df.loc[i, 'location_z'].values[0]
        # PROBLEM LINE
        if((df.loc[i]['player'][0]) == player_1) & (df.loc[i]['event'][0]) == 'PlayerMoveEvent')):
            player_1_location[0] = df.loc[i, 'location_x'].values[0]
            player_1_location[1] = df.loc[i, 'location_y'].values[0]
            player_1_location[2] = df.loc[i, 'location_z'].values[0]
        if ((None not in player_0_location) and (None not in player_1_location)):
            df.loc[i]['dist'] = (((player_0_location[0] - player_1_location[0]) ** 2) + ((player_0_location[1] - player_1_location[1]) ** 2) + ((player_0_location[2] - player_1_location[2]) ** 2)) ** 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt feels very [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), but I find that it often helps to treat Pandas more like a [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) language.

Here's how I would approach the problem statement (though note that I haven't tested this code):

```
# filter down to move events for just these two players
df_important_events = df.loc[(df['player'].isin([player_0, player_1])) & (df['event'] == 'PlayerMoveEvent')]

# make sure events are timestamp-ordered for the next step
df_important_events = df_important_events.sort_values(['timestamp'])

# filter down to the latest move event per player
df_latest_move_events = df_important_events.groupby('player').last().reset_index(drop=True)

if len(df_latest_move_events) != 2:
    # handle the case where the user passed in an invalid player, or one of the players has not moved yet

# filter down to just location columns
df_locations = df_latest_move_events[['location_x', 'location_y', 'location_z']]

# convert to numpy array of (x, y, z) tuples
locations_array = df_locations.to_records()

# return euclidean distance between the two locations
return numpy.linalg.norm(locations_array[1] - locations_array[0])
```